# how to simulate a train with different waggons using TweenMax and BezierPlugin

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, bezier

i am trying to animate a "train" along a dynamically created "track".
i am using the greensock TweenMax class and the bezier plugin to create the animation.
however, i would like the train to consist of three "waggons" that should all be animated along the track ( i.e. following each other )

somehow i seem to have a brainfreeze and cannot figure out how to achieve this.

any suggestions?

Comment: I’ve done that [without using the greensock TweenMax class and the bezier plugin](http://www.helloflash.net/Fichiers/HTML/CATEGORIES/bezier/bezier1.htm). The difficulty is that the motion of a body whose coordinates are calculated using the parametric form of the Bezier curve is not uniform. A method has therefore been used to cut the curve in equal parts. Thus the objects have a constant speed. The objects are not arranged at regular intervals as waggons, but the code can be adapted. Are you interested by the code ?

Comment: [Physics engine like Box2D would be cooler](http://www.sideroller.com/wck/).

Comment: Maths and graphics note: don't use Bezier curves for fixed-speed animation, unless you're going to first manually [trace it](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing). If you're not, it's an extremely poor curve choice.

Comment: thanks for helping.
i used TweenMax anyway and used multiple timelines and a delay for each "waggon" looks pretty good. box2d etc. would be overkill for my needs.